# Rails Heroku SSL https:// redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, https, dns, cname

I have a Rails 5 app with Heroku's SSL added. www.example.com and example.com works fine but when I preface my site with "https://" It doesn't work, but "http://" works.

I'm using Namecheap.com for my DNS. How do I go about getting "https://example.com" to direct to my heroku app?

Comment: If you host your server with Heroku, the port for https was opened by default if using herokuapp subdomain. But for a custom domain, you need to buy a SSL cert! https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint
2nd thing is not redirecting stuff actually, what you need to do is just configure a CNAME to point to your heroku app! https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Answer (score 12):

What you need to do is :

You need to have `SSL Endpoint` addon added to your `heroku` app

It will provide a `EndPoint URL` for your heroku app.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

And you need to add `SSL cert` configured brought from third party vendors.

Then you can add `CNAME` record with with given `EndPoint URL` from `SSL Endpoint` plugin.

Make sure to add this in `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.force_ssl = true
```

It will work then.

Comment: I bought and integrated an SSL certificate for Heroku. I'm using the new Heroku SSL integration, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl instead of Endpoint SSL.

If i set the CNAME for my root domain to the myapp.herokudns.com, I lose the ability to add MX Records to my root domain, thus not being able to accept emails to my domain name.